# UIPrintPageRenderer / HTML to PDF issue : extra blank space added in rendered PDF

Tags: ios, uiwebview, html-to-pdf, uiprintpagerenderer

We have an issue using UIPrintPageRenderer while rendering an HTML in UIWebview to PDF page.
The HTML contains a table with multiple rows (....) whose heights are known.

The UIWebView well renders that HTML but once transformed in PDF through UIPrintPageRenderer, it happens that extra spaces are added between rows.
See exemple attached with 2 rows of a table. An extra space has been added in the PDF whereas it doesn't exist in the HTML.
[image]
We use that library : https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf
Any help would be nice.
Regards,
Morgan.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use CSS in your html and specialise  with a specific height

```
body {
margin : 0;
}
```